# How to use table name with spaces in Web2PY and MSSQLSERVER database server

Tags: sql-server, web2py

I am getting error message  Field: invalid table name: [LMP Order History], use rname for "funny" names.

I am using web2py and MS SQLSERVER, I have table name with spaces.

How can I use rname for table names?

Web2py - 2.18.5
SQLSERVER - 2017

```
db.define_table('[LMP Order History]',
    Field('rID', type='Text')
    )
```

Field: invalid table name: [LMP Order History], use rname for "funny" names
Version
web2py™ Version 2.18.5-stable+timestamp.2019.04.08.04.22.03
Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/home/www-data/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 219, in restricted
    exec(ccode, environment)
  File "/home/www-data/web2py/applications/PFinance/models/db.py", line 117, in <module>
    migrate = False)
  File "/home/www-data/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/base.py", line 592, in define_table
    table = self.lazy_define_table(tablename, *fields, **kwargs)
  File "/home/www-data/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/base.py", line 604, in lazy_define_table
    table = table_class(self, tablename, *fields, **kwargs)
  File "/home/www-data/web2py/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/objects.py", line 250, in __init__
    'use rname for "funny" names' % tablename)
SyntaxError: Field: invalid table name: [LMP Order History], use rname for "funny" names
```

Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I am just start learning web2py, try this

```
db.define_table(' LMP_Order_History',
    Field('rID', type='Text')
    )
```

it will make the spaces.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I forgot to mention, I am using existing database. Table already exists in database. All I have to do is retrieve the data from the table and display in grid.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that '[LMP Order History]' would be useless as a name when trying to access the table via the DAL syntax: `db.[LMP Order History].insert(...)` would break Python

What you want is:

```
db.define_table('lmp_order_history',
    Field('rID', type='Text'),
    rname='[LMP Order History]'
    )
```